# how to close browser after execution of all testcase or after fail of testcase with protractor using selenium server with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am able to run testcases with protractor using selenium server with angularjs

I want to close my browser after execution of all testcase or after fail of testcase,

I am able to do this by writing `browser.close()` in the last testcase, but this will not work if testcase fails, is there any other way to close the browser in this case also, or is there any different name for after like `afterEach`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It require to put condition which tells browser that test case failed..can you please share your code please?

Comment: describe('Login', function () {
    var ptor;
  
    it('login', function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
        ptor.get('http://127.0.0.1:5100/login')
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('username')).sendKeys('rajit.garg');
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('password')).sendKeys('rajit');
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.buttonText('Login')).click()
    })
})

Comment: code above is my one testcase, how i can put condition to close browser, and is there any different name for after like afterEach, so instead of doing in all testcases I can put this into only one after block...?

Comment: Do you redirect user when login fails?

Comment: if login fails , I want to close my opened browser

Comment: I know that but do you redirecting user anywhere when login fails? or are you giving any message when login fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you login check for the title of the page, if it not desired page then you can call driver.quit else continue with your exection

Comment: I thing,Still no one is understanding my requirement, testcase can be failed at any point at any level due to any reason e.g. element not found or not clickable etc. then it means i have require to check all cases, I am simply want if any exception occur in testcase then it simply close the window and not to wait, also if all testcases passes of one describe then it close the window and then reopen if require by another describe testcases.

Comment: it wont happen automatically , you need to add conditions. you and add try catch finally blocks after every test case, if test case throws a exception it will go in catch and then you can close the window, and if the the test case is pass it will go in finally and you can close it again.

Comment: Welcome, accept my ans , it will increase my score :-)